# Any plans with the Stack Overflow theme?

Tags: discussion, design

I was recently hopping through the HNQ and noticed that [Puzzling.SE](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/) graduated, and had gotten its new design.

Looking though the other sites, I noticed that a lot of the other sites have something nice going for them in terms of design, even if only a little bit. Some examples:

- [Programmers](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/)
- [Electrical Engineering](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/)
- [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/)
- [Bicycles](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/)
- [Movies & TV](https://movies.stackexchange.com/)
- [The Workplace](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/)
- [Travel](https://travel.stackexchange.com/)

Pretty much all of the other sites on the Stack Exchange network have a little bit extra, but 
[Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/), [Super User](https://superuser.com/), and [Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/) do not. (There might be others that are plain, but these are just the ones I noticed).

I know that I can use user style sheets, and themes are what user style sheets are for. But I think it would be nice if SO could get in on the action that the other sites are getting.

I am not proposing a specific theme, or changing anything drastically, I'm just wondering if there were any plans to change/update the SO design (other than the minor color tweaks that just happened recently).

Comment: It has just had an update to tweak the colours a bit. I don't think you're going to see any major changes in the design at this stage.

Comment: SO is the original site.  It's not that it didn't change the theme from the default theme, but rather *the default theme was made to be the SO theme*.

Comment: @Servy, I know, along with Server Fault and Super User. However, I'm not asking *why* does SO have a plain theme, but rather, can it be made a little more special than it currently is.

Comment: @CaptJak i definitely agree there's room for some flair in the design ala other SE sites

Comment: @CaptJak Isn't it's plainness what makes it unique? :)

Comment: @Hynes, well it could... but I don't see why the greatest of sites on the SE network has to look like it isn't the greatest :(. Why does Code Review, or Puzzling get to look more appealing?

Comment: I like the minimalist design. Just what I need after having built obnoxiously and gratuitously "designed" websites all day.

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan, I didn't say it shouldn't be a minimalist design. Look at [Graphic Design](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/), for example.

Comment: To be honest, I prefer the SO design over all the others linked above. Some of them look a bit dated in this age of minimalism.

Comment: @Hynes Since minimalism is "in" and all the not-yet-graduated sites look almost identical.....no, not really.

Comment: I hate the new design of Puzzling.SE. That colorful gradient is too distracting. I don't want anything like that for SO.

Comment: Honestly, the color scheme of the new [Puzzling.SE] offends my eyes. The colors look like popular diseases, and the background is two disagreeing flashy colors with mostly [objectionable math](http://scottsievert.com/blog/2015/04/23/image-sqrt/) between them.

Answer (score 75, accepted):

I appreciate the question. [Puzzling.SE](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/) is a gorgeous website.

This is something that the Stack Overflow design team talks about semi-regularly. We imagine what it could look like and how we could improve the design. Yet these exercises never go very far for a few reasons:

1. We're still trying to catch-up with creating designs for the various Stack Exchange communities who have reached public beta, but unfortunately have not received a design yet. Before we start redesigning a current "graduated" community, we want to make sure every graduated community has a design.
2. We have other things we're working on (Jobs, Developer Story, Documentation, Mobile, Teams, Chat, etc).
3. Most of the design team thinks the current Stack Overflow works pretty well. Maybe it's not the flashiest site out there, but it works. This doesn't mean we couldn't improve it, but we aren't actively looking to redesign it either.
4. Our big effort right now is cleaning Stack Overflow up. Fixing the little things like odd tab padding and misaligned icons, as well as considering larger issues such as making navigation easier and thinking how we can make search better.

Whatever design changes we make, our primary concern is assisting people as they learn and share with each other.

Comment: Makes sense. Alright, well, hopefully this post can be a fence to hold back any other questions regarding this, as new sites get new designs.

Comment: I believe in the same. **Most of the design team thinks the current Stack Overflow works pretty well. Maybe it's not the flashiest site out there**

Comment: "... a gorgeous website" I wouldn't go quite that far. I like the logo and the gradient, but the text at the bottom of Puzzles is nigh unreadable due to lack of contrast with the overpowering teal wallpaper.

Comment: Call me a graphic design curmudgeon if you want (I grew up with ASCII terminals of 40 then 80 characters). I view (pun) design changes as empty calories. SO is visibly functional today, I'd rather see efforts in other areas. Having said that, years from now: it better look different.

Comment: Less Is More for me. I would hate to be confronted with the background from puzzling.se every time i'm here. In fact if that happened I would remove it from my end before my browser ever got the chance to render it.

Comment: I think one of the bugs that the team should be focused on right now is the broken reputation page in user profiles. The graph is still broken after all these years.

Comment: I agree with @TylerH, the text in the footer on Puzzling.SE has very poor contrast with the background. My far from heavily pondered suggestion would be white or yellow as an alternative.

Comment: @Derek朕會功夫 broken how?

Comment: @TylerH Go to the [reputation page (graph)](http://stackoverflow.com/users/2756409/tylerh?tab=reputation&sort=graph) and try changing the range. It won't work. Also the click/hover events on the bars are also broken.

Comment: @Derek朕會功夫 What browser are you on? Changing the range works for me. Just click and drag on the bottom graph and the top graph updates accordingly. Likewise, click/hover functionality is working fine for me. I've tested in the latest versions of Firefox, Chrome, and IE.

Comment: @TylerH Doesn't work for me: http://i.stack.imgur.com/2VeHW.gif I haven't been able to use it for years. Tested on <= Chrome 51.

Comment: @Derek朕會功夫 I would suggest creating a bug report for that bug if one hasn't already been created. I'll let the person who's on bug duty this week know about the issue.

Comment: @Derek朕會功夫 I'd recommend a fresh install of Chrome or resetting Chrome to 'factory' settings if there's an option for that (I don't use Chrome regularly), since it seems isolated to you. It could also be an add-on or disabled JavaScript at fault.

Comment: @Hynes [Created one on SE meta.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/279173/reputation-graph-not-interactable) Looks like it's related to touchscreens.

Comment: Almost a year later and I get the design change I wanted! :D